# Codeigniter HMVC Error Too Many Redirects on WHMCS

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, whmcs

I am using Codeigniter 2 with HMVC running well on localhost using XAMPP. After upload to WHMCS hosting, I got the error:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

In many references, temporary solved by clearing cookies or open private browser (ex: Chrome Incognito) only on first page (first load) then got the error:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

on next click or reload. Then I have to clear cookies or reopen private browser again.

There's no error on apache error log. How do I resolve this ?

Here's the screenshoot.

[image]

Comment: can we see the screenshot of it ?

Comment: i've just add the screenshoot above.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by setting the value of "$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']" to "TRUE"
In my case it’s due to sanitizing of cookie values by security class.
But Encryption of cookie data solves the problem.

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28378469/Diagnosing-the-cause-of-a-redirect-loop-in-a-CodeIgniter-app.html